# как считать поля input на клик?Jquery, js

Tags: javascript, jquery

нужно если клацнуть на save_subname тогда считать инпуты из всех row sale /все инпуты row subname

а если клацнуть на save_sale тогда считать инпуты из всех row sale кроме вложенных row subname

с кодом что я показал оно считывает все ипуты даже из row row subname хотя я их не сохранял
т.е сохраняю только save_sale а оно считывает и row subname

```js
// Массив куда всё сложим
var NewArr = [];
var Rows = $('.' + input_block);
// Перебираем их
for (let i = 0; i < Rows.length; i++) {
  // Создаём временный массив
  var tempArr = {};
  // Получаем все поля input из элемента с классом row(input_block)
  var inputs = Rows[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
  // Перебираем их
  for (let z = 0; z < inputs.length; z++) {
    // Получаем имя элемента input
    var name = inputs[z].getAttribute("name");
    // Во временный массив добавляем ключ name и значение в значение
    tempArr[name] = inputs[z].value;
  }
  // Добавляем временный массив в основной массив для каждого элемента с классом row
  NewArr.push(tempArr);
}
```

```html
<div class="row sale">
  <input name="id" type="text" value="2">
  <input name="sale" type="text" value="10">
  <div class="row subname">
    <input name="id" type="text" value="100">
    <input name="title" type="text" value="subname1">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="save_subname">Save</a>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="save_sale">Save</a>
</div>
<div class="row sale">
  <input name="id" type="text" value="4">
  <input name="sale" type="text" value="100">
  <div class="row subname">
    <input name="id" type="text" value="1">
    <input name="title" type="text" value="subname2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="save_subname">Save</a>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="save_sale">Save</a>
</div>
```

Спасибо!

Comment: начните с того, чтобы почитать про jquery чуть поболее, чем одна приведенная строка с `$('.'+input_block);` Потом нормально формализуйте логику, и добавьте нужным элементам нужные классы, чтобы их было легко обрабатывать.

Comment: input_block там соответсвенно может быть либо row sale либо row subname дело в том что row subname проблем нет я считываю данные только из этого блока, а если row sale то оно считывает и вложенный row subname

Comment: `$('.row.sale input');` и `$('.row.sale > input');`